# String to Image convertion in php and store in mysql database

Tags: php, android, mysql, string, image

I want to store an image(which is passed by an android developer) into mysql database. I'm working in PHP. Plz help me someone to script php code.

Actualy I asked half question. Main problem area is that how to store image in upload folder?

Comment: Actualy I asked half question. Main problem area is that how to store image in upload folder?

Comment: You can google for best practices o how to store image. There are many possibilities.

Comment: Refer this link to store image in upload folder:


   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27164016/upload-images-to-two-different-folders-in-server?noredirect=1#comment42821567_27164016

Answer (score 0):

use

```
file_get_contents($file)
```

That will return string content that you can store as TEXT in mysql DB.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this if the image has been sent using POST form [if you use DefaultHttpClient on Android side](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient.html):

```php
<?php
// Database connection
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);

// Prepare the query
$query = $conn->prepare(
    'INSERT INTO images_table (id, image_data) VALUES (:id, :data)'
);
// Bind data received by form
$query->bindParam(':id', $_POST['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->bindParam(':data', $_POST['image'], PDO::PARAM_LOB);
$query->execute();
?>
```

Hope it helps!

#### Edit: help sending data from Android:

[Here is a useful post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938502/sending-post-data-in-android):

```
public void postData() {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/yourscript.php");

    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image", image.toByteArray()));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
}
```

[An maybe here is another useful one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935946/sending-images-using-http-post).

Sorry, I haven't test it, consider it as a tip. The question is about PHP side.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
   $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);
   $query = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO images_table (id, image_data) VALUES (?, ?)');
   $query->execute(array($_POST['id'], $_POST['image']));
?>
```

Comment: You should avoid code only answers. Instead explain how the code works and how it answers the OP's question